# Multiword expression recognition in Spacy

Tags: spacy

I have a text along with index entries some of which indicate important multiword expressions (MWEs) that occur in the text (e.g. "spongy bone" for a biology text).  I would like to use the entries to construct a custom matcher in spaCy so that I can recognize occurrences of the MWEs in the text.  An additional requirement is that I need the match occurrences to retain the lemmatized representations and POS tags of the MWE constituent words.

I have looked at the existing spaCy examples that do similar things, but I can't seem to get the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

The Spacy documentaion is not very clear on using Matcher class with multiple phrase, but there is a multiphrase matching [example](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/multi_word_matches.py) in the Github repo.

I was faced with the same challenge recently, and I got it working as below. My text file contains a single record per line with a phrase and its description deliminated by '::'.

```
import spacy
import io
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = nlp(u'Your text here')
rules = list()

# Create a list of tuple of phrase and description from the file
with io.open('textfile','r',encoding='utf8') as doc:
    rules = [tuple(line.rstrip('\n').split('::')) for line in doc]

# convert the phrase string to a spacy doc object 
rules = [(nlp(item[0].lower()),item[-1]) for item in rules ]

# create a dictionary for accessing value using the string as the index which is returned by matcher class
rules_dict = dict()
for key,val in rules:
    rules_dict[key.text]=val

# get just the phrases from rules list
rules_phrases = [item[0] for item in rules]

# match using the PhraseMatcher class
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab,rules_phrases)
matches = matcher(text)
result = list()

for start,end,tag,label,m in matches:
    result.append({"start":start,"end":end,"phrase":label,"desc":rules_dict[label]})
print(result)
```

Comment: Could you pls provide a sample of your file for 'textfile'?